# Powershell: Win32_BIOS Serialnumber validity

Tags: powershell, directory, bios

In a system i'm making I am saving files from each computer to a directory which has the name of the serialnumber i collect from this code:

```
$serialnr = gwmi -computer $compname Win32_BIOS | ForEach {$_.SerialNumber}
```

When I run this code on my computer I get the serialnumber, however when the same code is run on a friends computer the output reads: "FFFFFFF" (I am not sure about the number of F's).

What I'm hoping is that "FFFFFFF" is like a standard output if I cannot get the true serialnumber, then I could atleast use that as a parameter for another command to make "fix".

Q: Anybody has some information about the possible outputs from this command, or possible fixes?

All ideas and all help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Directly from the bios of friend's computer can you read the right serial number?

Comment: Just a wild guess: Has your friend an UEFI board? Maybe Win32_BIOS has problems with UEFI.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the purpose of your ForEach. Am I missing something?

```
$serialnr = gwmi win32_bios | select -Expand serialnumber | out-string
```

will give you the serial number.

Comment: Yeah foreach was useless in this case, my bad.. Thanks!
But it does not solve my problem =/